# Is it possible to mount both back and front cameras at the same time on a react native expo app?

Tags: react-native, mobile-development, react-native-camera, react-native-vision-camera

I'm currently working on a react native expo app and I have a camera feature that currently records allows playback of videos recorded with the front camera. I want to add a functionality where both front and back cameras record at the same time. Is this possible? I know react-native-vision-camera is a package I can use for the single camera recording but is there any way to implement multi-camera capture?

So far I've looked into the react-camera expo package and react-vision-camera package but haven't found any resources/tutorials online on how to start implementing this feature. Any help/tips are appreciated

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/can-we-use-the-front-back-camera-at-the-same-time-on-android-3e6558c1b12a here's an excellent article about trying it on Android - tldr most phones don't support it.